# Cannot store github credentials on aws

Tags: linux, git, amazon-web-services, github, amazon-ec2

I created a brand new github account and then a new repository.
Also, I created a github token.
Locally on my mac, I run a

```
git push
```

and the first time I had to enter username and github-token.
After that, it seems terminal never asks for username or password/token.

Then I logged in into my ec2 server and did the same:

```
git clone myrepo
username: my_username
passowrd: my_token
```

And I was able to get the code.
After that, each time I make a pull in my ec2 server, it always prompts for username/password.
So for some reason mac stores credentials but aws doesn't.
It seems you need some application?
I had a look at this:

```
https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/caching-your-github-credentials-in-git
```

But it seems there is no available version for my ec2? What I understand it uses its own linux distro, called Amazon Linux 2. So the question is: is there a credential manager for aws ec2?

Answer (score 4):

Have you following the instruction?

**Link**: https://github.com/GitCredentialManager/git-credential-manager/blob/main/docs/credstores.md#gits-built-in-credential-cache

> **Git's built-in credential cache**
> Available on: Windows, macOS, Linux
>
> ```
> export GCM_CREDENTIAL_STORE=cache
> # or
> git config --global credential.credentialStore cache
> ```
>
> This credential store uses Git's built-in ephemeral in-memory
> credential cache. This helps you reduce the number of times you have
> to authenticate but doesn't require storing credentials on persistent
> storage. It's good for scenarios like Azure Cloud Shell or AWS
> CloudShell, where you don't want to leave credentials on disk but also
> don't want to re-authenticate on every Git operation.
>
> By default, git credential-cache stores your credentials for 900
> seconds. That, and any other options it accepts, may be altered by
> setting them in the environment variable GCM_CREDENTIAL_CACHE_OPTIONS
> or the Git config value credential.cacheOptions. (Using the --socket
> option is untested and unsupported, but there's no reason it shouldn't
> work.)
>
> ```
> export GCM_CREDENTIAL_CACHE_OPTIONS="--timeout 300"
> # or
> git config --global credential.cacheOptions "--timeout 300"
> ```

Comment: I just update my answer with quote instruction from this link. Thank you for your review, I'm new contributor in stack-overflow. Any things should improve?

Comment: Thank you for updating your answer. "Any things should improve?"—the [answer] page has some good tips on writing good answers. Good luck!

Comment: unfortunately github deprecated this on August 2021. https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/about-remote-repositories#cloning-with-https-urls